# regexp in ON clause produces error

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am running on a postgresql 8.2.15 database.

I am trying to run a query that does a join using regular expressions.  My current query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM USCITY a join USCITY2 b
ON b.usps in regexp_matches(a.city, '.* (?= [^\\s]*, [^\\s]*$)');
```

this produces the error:

```
 "ERROR: syntax error at or near "regexp_matches"
 Position: 101"
```

I have checked to see that the regexp_matches function works using

```
SELECT regexp_matches(city, '.* (?= [^\\s]*, [^\\s]*$)')
FROM CITY2;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to use comma separated literals with the `IN` operator, or a sub-select, like `ON b.usps IN (SELECT * FROM regexp_matches(...))` if `b.usps` is an array, but most likely you want `ON b.usps IN (SELECT m[0] FROM regexp_matches(...) m)`